# How to change font (family) of comments in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, comments, syntax-highlighting

How to change font (font family/name) of comments in Eclipse? I can do it in NetBeans, but is it even possible in Eclipse? In Window -> Preferences -> C/C++ -> Editor -> Syntax Coloring I can change only the colour of the fonts, but I would like to change also the font itself.

(I'm using Eclipse Juno.)

Answer (score 0):

Try Window->Preferences->General->Appearance->Colors and Fonts.  I'm using Eclipse Kepler, so I'm not sure this is available in Juno.

Comment: I see "text font" and "editor text font" among other options. Is there one specifically for comments, do you know?

Comment: OK.  There may not be a setting specifically for comments.  I'll keep looking.